# Detect Tap on Sprite in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a Cocos2d game that has between 4 - 12 sprites that the users can interact with (either drag and drop or tap).  If a user taps on one of the sprites, I'd like that sprite to move back to it's previous position (prior to being dragged and dropped).  Is there a way to detect a tap vs. a drag action?

Comment: I'm tempted to just say "Yes". Recognizers or time&position diff between touch began and ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using touch delegate create a boolean of isDrag and set in "CCMoved". Then check that in "CCTouchEnded". e.g

```
(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

return YES;
```

}

(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

```
isDrag = YES;
```

}

(void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if(isDrag){

```
 }else{

 }
```

}